# How to convert a terminal recording to a GIF?

Tags: 20.04, ffmpeg, multimedia

I made a terminal record with the `script` tool.

```
mediainfo video 
General
Complete name                            : video
File size                                : 1.29 KiB
```

I can play it with `scriptreplay`. Is it possible to convert it to a GIF, for example with `ffmpeg` or another program?

To clarify, I mean [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages//artful/man1/script.1.html) from the `bsdutils` package, not a program script. I thought that the saved file is a kind of video, so I can grep some frames/pictures and create a GIF of it.

I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A nice option is to use [`ttyrec`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ttyrec.1.html) instead of `script` to record your terminal activity and then convert it to a GIF using [`ttygif`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ttygif.1.html).

1. Install the `ttyrec` and `ttygif` packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install ttyrec ttygif
   ```
2. Open a terminal and start `ttyrec` to record your terminal:

   ```
   ttyrec
   ```

   Running `ttyrec` without an argument will save the recording in a file named `ttyrecord` in your current folder. You can specify a filename as an argument to save the file with this name.
3. Use your terminal.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to stop recording.
5. To convert the recording to a GIF, run:

   ```
   ttygif ttyrecord
   ```

   If you saved the recording with another filename, change `ttyrecord` to the filename you used.

   This command will save the recording as a GIF with the name `tty.gif`.

---

Here is a GIF I created with the above procedure that contains the above procedure:

[image: GIF containing the above procedure]

---

**Notes**

- If you get this error when you run `ttygif`:

  ```
  Error: WINDOWID environment variable was empty
  ```

  you need to run the following command before running `ttygif`:

  ```
  export WINDOWID=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)
  ```

  The above command needs `xdotool`. You can install it using:

  ```
  sudo apt install xdotool
  ```

  Reference: https://github.com/icholy/ttygif#additional-notes
- `ttygif` does not work with qterminal for some reason. Use another terminal for the conversion instead.

  I have confirmed that it works fine with kitty, it's slow with GNOME terminal, and it's extremely fast with XTerm.
- The `ttygif` command can produce big-size directories in `/tmp`. I recommend removing them manually after the conversion using:

  ```
  rm -r /tmp/ttygif.*
  ```

Comment: Nice colors :) ... +1

Comment: @Raffa Thank you! I'm using `zsh` with the [spaceship prompt](https://spaceship-prompt.sh/). My terminal is [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) and the theme I use is [Argonaut](https://github.com/daveyarwood/kitty-themes#argonaut). :)